# node.js express.js routing of root Redirecting to //

Tags: node.js, express

I want to route root route (http://server:5000/) in my node.js express.js application:

When I go to http://server:5000/ I get:
Redirecting to //

I get the same message if I have a route:

app.get('/', routes.index);

What can be the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was a bug in Windows with Connect: https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/issues/427

You should update or set the redirect option to false in the Connect static middleware.