# node.js express app creation equivalent in Windows 7

Tags: node.js, powershell, windows-7, express, pug

I'm following [this](http://shapeshed.com/creating-a-basic-site-with-node-and-express/) tutorial on node.js and express.

The author is on a UNIX machine. To create the app skeleton with express, jade, and stylus, the author says to run the command

```
./node_modules/express/bin/express -t jade -c stylus
```

However, I'm on a Windows 7 machine, so this command doesn't work. `./node_modules/express/bin/express jade stylus` doesn't do what is desired either.

What is the equivalent of the author's command for Windows PowerShell?

Comment: I would highly recommend installing Virtual Box and creating an Ubuntu (or similar) virtual machine for Node development. Most tutorials, samples, and help will expect that you are using Linux. Also most packages that you will want to use will never have been tested on a Windows machine which means things occasionally fail in mystifying ways.

Comment: @Bill You were completely correct. I ran into this problem: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8648581/node-js-express-js-routing-of-root-redirecting-to?rq=1).

Comment: Yep, this will just be the first of many :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express can be installed "globally". That means that the OS will create a link to `express` in the command line that will run the express application creator.

Just add a `-g` option while installing and then call `express` directly without the path to `node_modules`:

```
C:\project>npm install express -g
C:\project>express --sessions --css stylus --ejs myapp
```

I recommend you to follow the official guide: http://expressjs.com/guide.html. The tutorial you're following is for Express 2.* and Express 3 changed a bit.

Comment: I see. Would you recommend that I abandon that tutorial then?

Comment: I wouldn't recommend installing dependencies globally like this. If you later need to update to Express 4, all of your applications that were developed expecting Express 3 will probably break.

Comment: Bill is right. The first part of the Express Guide shows you how to install it locally, using a package.json file. That's the best idea since you can then share the code with that json file and every other programmer can install it without having to manually get all dependencies.